# Community Sharing Set

Tags: community, sharing-sets

I am trying to determine the creation date & creator of a community sharing set.  I am looking for direction on how I can determine this.

Comment: Did you try the Setup Audit Trail?

Comment: In the audit trail I see information related to changes to standard sharing settings.  However, I am not seeing information related to changes to community sharing settings.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a simple way to view the change history for sharing sets for Communities.

The changes do not appear in the Setup Audit trail which can be accessed via Setup>Security>View Setup Audit Trail or in the Site history which can be accessed by going to Setup>All Communities>Workspaces>Settings>Administration>Pages>Go to Site.Com Studio then select the Change History - this will show when a community has been published but again omits the Sharing Sets

[image: Site Change History]